# temporarily disable recentf without writing the list to disk?

Tags: recentf, dashboard

I'm trying out the [dashboard](https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard) package and noticed that my `.org` files kept getting added to the recentf list, because `dashboard` uses OrgMode to generate the agenda that it displays.

So I added code to `dashboard` that boils down to:

```
;; When rendering the dashboard, do the following:

;; if recentf mode is on, turn it off
;; so we don't add items to the Most Recently Used list:
    (if (recentf-enabled-p) (recentf-mode -1))

;; render the dashboard by rendering each widget

;; if recentf mode was originally on, turn it back on
;; this is pseudocode, of course :)
    (if (recentf-WAS-enabled-p) (recentf-mode))
```

This works (I'm not saving the information into my recentf list) but this also has the effect of saving my recentf list every time that I disable `recentf-mode`.  This happens every time I switch back to the `dashboard` buffer.

My question: **is there a way to disable `recentf-mode`without flushing the list to disk?**

What I'm really trying to do is temporarily get recentf-mode to stop recording new entries in the list - I'm only turning it off because there doesn't seem to be another way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let-bind `find-file-hook` to prevent Recentf from recording the file, e.g.,

```
(let ((find-file-hook (remq 'recentf-track-opened-file find-file-hook)))
  (find-file "test.txt"))
```

Then to bypass Recentf during `M-x org-agenda`, use this:

```
(define-advice org-agenda (:around (old-fun &rest args) skip-recentf)
  (let ((find-file-hook (remq 'recentf-track-opened-file find-file-hook)))
    (apply old-fun args)))
```

I don't know about Dashboard, but I think the same technique should work, maybe simply replacing `org-agenda` with `dashboard-get-agenda`.